# how to clear the fields in a jface Wizard on pressing the back button

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

I have created a JFace wizard `PCWizard` extending `Wizard` and have four pages 
`PCPageOne` ,`PCPageTwo`, `PCPageThree` and  `PCPageFour` extending `WizardPage`.

1. When I reach the last page I want the back and cancel button disabled.
2. when I press the back button on other pages I want the data in the widgets of the page to get cleared and when I press next again  I want the text fields to be empty so that the next button doesn't get activated .

I have also captured the data collected in another class, if u want me to override the `WizardDialog`  class and do the action how do I do it . I'm new to java and SWT a more elaborate explanation would be fine.Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `WizardPage` `setVisible` method to clear fields when the page becomes active:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(final boolean visible)
{
  super.setVisible(visible);

  if (visible) {
    // TODO clear your fields
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks greg, This worked....,I have another doubt , how to make a come to first page when a link/button is pressed on the last Wizard page of the wizard and should function like a normal newly opened wizard..., I've tried by calling the first by keeping a selection listener but the other pages but the next is not being enabled, could you look into it..

Answer (score 0):

To disable the back button do the following in the last page:

```
@Override
public IWizardPage getPreviousPage() {
    // prevent going back
    return null;
}
```

Also clearing the input in pages might be done in a `IPageChangedListener`:

```
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), wizard);
dialog.addPageChangedListener(new IPageChangedListener() {
    public void pageChanged(PageChangedEvent event) {
        // this is just a suggestion..
        IClearablePage page = (IClearablePage)event.getSelectedPage();
        page.clear();
    }
});
```

Where `IClearablePage` is your own interface with a `clear()`, and all your pages implement `IClearablePage`.

EDIT: override `setVisible` as greg stated in his answer is probably more convenient.